# How to grab posts in Gutenberg Block?

Tags: block-editor

Trying to get latest 10 posts to display in a Gutenberg plugin, but I can't figure out how to access the latest posts from the block.js. I know how to do it from PHP and it's easy, but this is new to me. Do I have to make a request to the REST API or is there a better practice?

Comment: You may also be able to use the `wp.api` https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/ in this case `wp.api.posts`, I'm about to test this myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use the REST API. You can access the latest posts by calling:

```
wp.apiFetch( { path: '/wp/v2/posts' } ).then( posts => {
    console.log( posts );
} );
```

Here is some more information on using the package - https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-api-fetch/

Comment: Sweet. I thought I might. Thank you for confirming.